# Query mongo db for an array

Tags: mongodb

```
slot1.attributes = [a,b]
slot2.attributes = [c,d]  query_attributes_list = [a,b,c,d,e]
slot3.attributes = [e,f]
```

I want to query the slot that has all attribute existed in query_attributes_list.
For the above example, it will return slot1 and slot2. Slot 3 has "f" attribute doesn't belong to query_attributes_list.
Does anyone know how can query in this case for MongoDB?

Comment: MongoDB aggregation query has set operators; the [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @prasad_. That what I looking for.